# Почему не работает background-image?

Tags: html, css, laravel

Проект написан на ларавель resources/views/welcome.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="bootstrap-3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="bootstrap-3/css/header_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ggg">gggg</div>
    <img src="images/earth.png">
</body>
```

Файл bootstrap-3/css/header_style.css:

```
.ggg {
background-image: url("images/earth.png");   // пробовал еще и так  url(images/earth.png)  url('images/earth.png')
height: 200px;
}
```

Картинка earth.png из свойства background-image не срабатывает... в то время, как от тега img она работает...В чем может быть причина?
П.С.: файл header_style.css подключен верно и работает (решил не засорять код примерами его работы)

Comment: А хватает размера маленького блока gggg чтобы узреть фон? Размер фона на размер блока не влияет...

Comment: ну....у меня вообще никаких настроек на блок div class=ggg не стоит кромеbackground, ну сейчас задам параметры попробую

Comment: размер совпадает.....рисунок влазит в блок

Comment: В теге img путь просчитывается относительно html-файла, в css - относительно файла css

Comment: )) приведите URL к этой странице

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS хранится в своей папке, и при обращении к картинке он пытается в своей папке найти папку images и в ней уже картинку.
Попробуйте поиграть с путем файла посредством ("../") в начале пути. Это поднимает ссылку по каталогам на один уровень вверх.

```html
background-image: url("../images/earth.png");
```

Answer (score 5):

`images/earth.png` - это относительный путь.

То есть если у тебя css файл лежит скажем в

```
www/bootstrap-3/css/header_style.css
```

а картинка

```
www/images/earth.png
```

то для подклчения в css нужен путь `../../images/earth.png` (2 каталога вверх по иерархии - до корня сайта)

Либо используй абсолютный путь вида `/images/earth.png`

Answer (score 4):

Действительно, попробуйте полный путь. Ведь  фоновый рисунок запрашивается после загрузки сайта. Если у Вас есть редирректы или ЧПУ, то запрос рисунка фона будет URL+image/earth.png. Проверьте, нет ли тут конфликта...

Comment: DNS, спасибо за совет и я уверен, что оно сработает,но есть один момент... сейчас я делаю это на локальном сервере (адресс будет один), потом залью на рабочий сервер (адресс измениться), а после уже дам человеку и он сам себе будет заливать на хостинг (третий адрес)...поэтому Ваше предложение в моем случае не актуально...

Comment: Смысл в том, чтобы через Инспектор кода посмотреть, какой адрес отдается для картинки из CSS. Обычно этого хватает для устранения проблемы.

Comment: @Александр так храните URL сайта в переменной и, если что, формируйте ссылку от  него. Я так тоже напоролся на проблемы с переносом от локали - ЧПУ меняло адресацию всех относительных ссылок.

Comment: DNS, спасибо за рекомендацию!))буду так делать в дальнейшем, это, действительно очень удобно!но хотелось бы разобраться все-таки с внутренними адресами и понять где я что-то упустил...

Comment: @Александр, или задавайте новый вопрос (тут уже нагромождение), или разбирайтесь по ситуации. Сложностей особых нет - загружаются инструкции стилей/картинок и идет запрос на их содержимое. Но запрос делает браузер и формирует ссылки от базы (URL). А эта база мжет быть искажена ЧПУ, редирректом и т.п.

Comment: DNS, проблема НЕ решена!!!Вы мне предложили вариант, который в МОЕМ случае применять антилогично! По поводу переменной - эт для моих личных проектов будет очень хорошо!А так...я просто одно из звеньев, которое участвует в этом  и вносить переменную, о которой буду знать только я -крайне не логично в этой ситуации

Comment: Хорошо, зададим вопрос более конкретно, Вы правы

Comment: Ну тогда покажите .htaccess, адрес сайта из браузера. Может, в них и кроется неправильный запрос к картинкам. По приведенным данным могу только догадываться, о чем и сообщаю

Answer (score 3):

`<img src="images/earth.png">` или - как в CSS - `image/earth.png` - есть небольшая разница в названиях директорий: **images** и **image**.

По всей видимости, причина в этом. (ответ на *первую версию* вопроса).

Ответ на *вторую версию* вопроса: (в любом случае где-то указан неверный путь к картинке из CSS файла).

Если прописать полный путь к картинке в CSS (с http://) - должно работать. Где-то путь неверный, в этом все дело.

Обычно для устранения проблемы достаточно посмотреть через Инспектор кода, какой адрес отдается для картинки из CSS, и понять, где затык.

Comment: да, спасибо, исправили, но эт я просто невнимательно написал в вопросе, я сделал изменение, проблема остается открытой...

Comment: Если прописать полный путь к картинке в CSS (с http://) - должно работать. Где-то путь неверный, в этом все дело.

Comment: просто мне нужно КОНКРЕТНЫЙ файл, который у меня в проекте, а по ссылке работает, конечно же. В том то и вопрос, что я не могу понять ГДЕ именно я с путями напутал....

Answer (score 2):

Советую открыть консоль разработчика в Chrome F12, открыть вкладку network и посмотреть URL по которому подгружается изображение и найти проблему.
Что касается пути, попробуйте такой вариант `/images/earth.png`